# Obtaining an Access_token to read Page Insights

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-insights

I've been working on using python to get access to Facebook insights information. I was able to get public information (e.g. 'likes' from cocacola's page) in addition to app insights for apps that I have developed.

Because I am the admin and developer for both pages and apps, when I go to facebook.com/insights I will see a section for pages and a section for apps. I want to be able to get insights for both from the graph api and store them on my personal database. Getting the app insights were not difficult. I obtained my app_id and app_secret when I created my app and then followed the process under App Login at this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. This gave me an app access_token which I could use to get app insights.

When attempting to do the same for pages, I have had more trouble. As many previous posts have mentioned, most of the facebook documentation has to do with a facebook app getting an access_token to manage or read insights from a page. I understand that this is useful for apps that interact with a user's page. However, my instinct says that I should be able to get an access token with read_insights for a page that I am the administrator of without having to go through an external app.

The only way that I've been able to read the insights for my page has been using the Graph Api Explorer. I used the Explorer to obtain an access_token (through the access_token button, allowing the Explorer to access my personal data and requested manage_pages and read_insight extended permision). Then I followed the instructions under Page Login at the /docs/authentication/ page that I posted above, to get an access_token for the facebook page I administer. Then I could finally run https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/insights?access_token=RETRIEVED_TOKEN. However, this is an incredibly cumbersome way of finding the access_token. Is there a way to get this token that is less cumbersome? Thanks for your help. I've been struggling with this for quite a while.

I've also included the code that I used to get the access token for my app.

```
def get_access_token():
    args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, client_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, grant_type="client_credentials" )
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args)
    response = urlparse.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    access_token = response['access_token'][0]
    return access_token
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using classic way:

- Create an app and login to it using facebook (JS SDK for example), with the **offline_access** and **read_insights** permission.
  The offline_access will give you a permanent access_token that you can use to access the insights anytime you want.
- The JS SDK (method FB.login) will return an object, containing the access_token you need.